# Keras model structure questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, keras

I'm following [this tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) on using Keras to train a basic conv-net. I find a couple of things confusing though, and the Keras documentation doesn't go into much detail either.

Let's look at the first few layers of the network:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

My Questions:

1. The tutorial describes the first layer as the "input layer". However, the first line includes a `Convolution2D` function, with a `input_shape`. Am I correct in assuming that this is actually the first *hidden* layer (a convolution layer), rather than just the *input* layer? Reason being that we don't need a separate `model.add()` statement just for the input?
2. In the `Convolution2D()` function, we're using 32 filters, each filter being 3x3 pixels. In my understanding, a filter is a small block of pixels which "scans" across the image. So for a 28x28 image, wouldn't we need 676 filters (26*26, since each filter is 3x3)? What does the `32` here mean?
3. The last line is a Dropout layer. From my understanding, Dropout is a regularization technique, and it's applied to the whole network. So does the `Dropout(0.25)` here apply a 25% dropout only to the previous layer? Or does it apply to all layers preceding it?

Thanks.

Comment: Im not gonna post an answer as it would be incomplete so :
1. yes, the "input layer" is in fact just a passive layer that just pass the input data to the first hidden layer
3. it only applies to the previous (in fact, the current layer until you add another in the sequential model), but not all layers can have dropout. Convolutionnal layers don't as they use other regularization techniques. Dense have dropout, Recurrent too but with a different syntax (keywords arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Whenever you call model.fit(), you are passing the 28 * 28 image. So that is the input to the model.
   On top of that input, we then are doing convolution to generate feature maps.
2. Convolution means matrix multiplication. So the output of a single filter in the first layer is 26 * 26 matrix. We have such 32 matrices. That is what 32 means. Check this for further explanation. https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/
3. This applies dropout with probability 0.25 to the layer preceding the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but regarding 3, I've been told by others that dropout applies to the previous layer, not the following one? So in this case, the 0.25 dropout applies to the MaxPool layer, is that right?

Comment: You are right. I had misinterpreted the source code. let me correct the answer